# Get Posts by Tag in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I want to get Posts in My Home Template with specific tag "iinluv"
I have written query codes but failed.
Here are my Codes.

```
<ul class="team-list">
<?php   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'tag' => 'iinluv', 'posts_per_page' => -1, );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;   $title = get_the_title();   $ptitle = $title;?>



<!-- TEAM THUMB -->
<li class="team-block bg-alt">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog imageproduct'); ?>

</li>
<!-- TEAM THUMB -->
<?php endwhile;?>

            </ul>
```

Please Check My Code and give me good suggestion to make it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `WooCommerce` as you have assigned `product` as `post_type`. To get posts from certain tag or category you have to use `tax_query`. Check following example.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'iinluv',
      ),
    ),
  );
```